# Quadratic residues in finite field

Tags: number-theory, algorithms, finite-fields, quadratic-residues, quadratic-reciprocity

For an integer $a$ and a finite field $F_{q}$ of odd order, what is the efficient algorithm   to determine $a$ is Quadratic residue or not?

Comment: By the way: the correct usage is "a criterion"; criteria is plural.

Comment: Maybe try this -> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_symbol#Calculating_the_Jacobi_symbol

Comment: @sharding4 what is the relation of Jacobi symbol and Finite field?

Comment: I guess it depends on whether your $q$ is a prime or a power of a prime.  For $q$ a prime the Legendre-Jacobi symbol $\big(\frac{d}{p}\big) = 1$ iff $a$ is a quadratic residue.

Comment: Let $q=p^n$, $p$ odd, $n\geq 1$. What do you mean with *integer* $a$? That $a$ is in the base field $\mathbb{F}_p$, whence $a^p=a$?

Answer (score 4):

The nonzero $a\in \Bbb F_q$ ($q$ odd) is a square iff $a^{(q-1)/2}=1$.

Comment: I wonder if there is a more efficient algorithm.

Comment: It is reasonably efficient, if you do the exponentiation by repeated squaring: it takes $O(\log q)$ field operations.

Comment: Echoing @RobertIsrael's comment: exponentiation by "repeated squaring" _is_ (rightly) considered an efficient algorithm. The fact that this algorithm is really an algorithm to evaluate the otherwise-simple expression $a^{(q-1)/2}$ is perhaps a distraction, but is fairly typical of number-theoretic algorithms.

Answer (score 3):

Let $q=p^n$, $p$ odd, $n\geq 1$.

As [already stated](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2332700/75794),
$a\in\mathbb{F}_q^\times$ is a square
if and only if $a^{(q-1)/2}=1$.

Remember the Frobenius automorphism and the definition of the norm $N(a)$
for field extensions? This leads to
$$\begin{align}
    \frac{q-1}{2} &= \frac{p-1}{2}(1+p+p^2+\cdots+p^{n-1})
\\\therefore\quad
    a^{(q-1)/2} &= \Bigl(\underbrace{
    a^1 a^p a^{p^2} \cdots a^{p^{n-1}}
    }_{N(a)\in\mathbb{F}_p}\Bigr)^{(p-1)/2}
\end{align}$$
Accordingly, $a$ is a square if and only if $N(a)$ is
a square in the base field $\mathbb{F}_p$,
therefore if and only if
$$\left(\frac{N(a)}{p}\right)_2=+1$$
and there are efficient Jacobi symbol algorithms for that,
e.g. the binary algorithm by [Shallit and Sorenson (1993)](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.43.9089).

It remains to compute $N(a)$.

- If $a$ itself is in the base field $\mathbb{F}_p$ (maybe that is what you meant when you spoke of *integer* $a$), then $N(a) = a^n$ and
  $$\left(\frac{N(a)}{p}\right)_2 =
  \left(\frac{a^n}{p}\right)_2 =
  \left(\frac{a}{p}\right)_2^n =
  \left(\frac{a}{p}\right)_2^{n\bmod{2}}$$
  Consequently:

  - If $n$ is even, then every $a\in\mathbb{F}_p^\times$
    is a square of some element in $\mathbb{F}_q^\times$.
  - If $n$ is odd, then $a\in\mathbb{F}_p^\times$ is a square
    in $\mathbb{F}_q^\times$ if and only if it is a square in
    $\mathbb{F}_p^\times$, that is, if and only if
    $\bigl(\frac{a}{p}\bigr)_2=+1$.
- If $a$ is not restricted to the base field, then computing $N(a)$
  is probably easiest with a
  [normal basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_basis)
  which takes the form
  $$\left(\beta, \beta^p, \beta^{p^2}, \ldots, \beta^{p^{n-1}}\right)$$
  with a suitable $\beta\in\mathbb{F}_q^\times$.
  The nice thing about such a basis is that taking $p$-th powers amounts
  to nothing more than a cyclic shift of the coefficient vector.
  Thus, obtaining the Frobenius conjugates of $a$ is very cheap, and
  you just need to multiply those $n$ conjugates together to obtain
  $N(a)$.

  With other bases, you can still resort to a square-and-multiply scheme,
  as [suggested by Robert Israel](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2332698/#comment-4802435).
  But then computing $N(a)$ has roughly the same computational cost
  as computing $a^{(q-1)/2}$: Both take $\operatorname{O}(\log q)$
  field multiplications. There is probably no point in going via $N(a)$ then.

Comment: -1 is not quadratic residue in $F_{3}$ but it is in $F_{9}$. because $i^2=-1$ and $i \in F_{9}$.@ccorn

Comment: @SoheilMemarian: Exactly, as stated: For $\mathbb{F}_9$, $n$ is even.

Comment: why is $a$ quadratic residue in $F_{p}_{*}$ if it is in $F_{q}_{*}$ for odd n?@ccorn

Comment: Answer updated accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how you have your finite field elements represented.  Finite fields have cyclic multiplicative groups, which means you have a generator $\alpha$ and then every (nonzero) element can be represented as a power of $\alpha$.  Often there is a built-in table of the elements represented as these powers, if the exponent is even then the element is a quadratic residue.